# How to use sympy to output the function image of the function returned by dsolve like matlab

Tags: python, matlab, sympy

I can use Matlab to output a function image of the solution to the following differential equation.

How can I do this in Python?

```matlab
% dsolve 计算
syms y(t) r V
eqn = diff(y) == -r / V * y;
cond = y(0) == 1;
y = dsolve(eqn, cond)
y = subs(y, r, 3.663959132E10);
y = subs(y, V, 4871E9)
fplot(y, [1, 1000])
format longG
val = double(solve(y == 0.05, t))
r5d
```

Comment: The “function image”? What is that? Are you talking about the plot `fplot(y, [1, 1000])`?

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you the same result as the Matlab :

```
import sympy as sp

r = sp.Symbol('r')
V = sp.Symbol('V')
t= sp.Symbol('t')
y = sp.Function('y')

diffeq = sp.Eq(y(t).diff(t) , -r / V * y(t))

y = sp.dsolve(diffeq, ics={y(0): 1})

y = y.subs(r, 3.663959132e10)

y = y.subs(V, 4871e9)

sp.plotting.plot(y.rhs, (t, 1, 1000))

val = list(sp.solveset(y.rhs-0.05, domain=sp.S.Reals))
```